# How to use sed to examine the line without specific content?

Tags: command-line, sed

I made a toy file named toy, its content is like:

```
aaa
bbb
```

My first idea is to use:

```
sed -n '/[^a]/ p' toy
bbb
```

it prints out bbb, but when I added

```
bb ab
```

to the end of toy file. I found it lose its power

```
sed -n '/[^a]/ p' toy
bbb
bb ab
```

How should I scan the whole line with the pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but you're asking sed to remove the lines that start with character a. (`^` means begin of line) It seems it does exactly just that.

Comment: in a [ ] I believe its an anti-direction search

Comment: @mtak, anyway, problem solved already

Comment: could you post that as an answer so it might be useful to other people as well?

Comment: A caret ("hat") at the beginning of a character group ([]) means the complementary group, i.e. everything that is *not* contained in the group. So `[^a]` means match anything that is not `a`.

Answer (score 0):

by using

```
sed '/a\+/d' toy
```

you can print out any line without any 'a' in the file.